# How to use a value from a struct dictionary and convert it to another type?

Tags: swift

Here I want to be able to use the value returned from an array. It returns as a type from a struct. I'm unsure of how to use the value as an integer.

```
struct Item: Codable {
let data: [String : Datum]
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let value: Int
}

var array = Item(data: ["1" : Datum(value: 1),"2": Datum(value: 2), "3":Datum(value: 3)])
var keyArray = ["1", "2", "3"]

print(array.data[keyArray[0]]!)
// Prints Datum(value: 1)

print(array.data[keyArray[0]]! + 1)
//This produces an error "Cannot convert value of type 'Datum' to expected argument type 'Int'"
//Expected result should be 2
```

My use case is when I get returned a decoded JSON it normally comes back as a dictionary. I'm wanting to use the values returned with a key but I feel like I'm one step short.

**Context**

Full JSON [Link](https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest)

I'm going to retrieve values from this JSON. (Example from large JSON file)

```
{"data":{"2":{"high":179,"highTime":1628182107,"low":177,"lowTime":1628182102},"6":{"high":189987,"highTime":1628179815,"low":184107,"lowTime":1628182100},"8":{"high":190800,"highTime":1628181435,"low":188100,"lowTime":1628182095}
}}
```

The string in front refers to an item ID.

The struct that I came up to decode goes like this.

```
// MARK: - Single
struct Single: Codable {
    let data: [String: Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable {
    let high, highTime: Int
    let low, lowTime: Int?
}
```

From there I'm planning to iterate through the JSON response to retrieve the item prices I'd want.

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dataFromURL: Single = Single(data: [:])
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            
        }
        .onAppear {
            async {
                try await decode()
                
            }
        }
    }
        
    func decode() async throws -> Single {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let urlString = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { throw APIError.invalidURL }
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else { throw APIError.invalidServerResponse }
        guard let result = try? decoder.decode(Single.self, from: data) else { throw APIError.invalidData }
        //We copy our result to an existing variable
        dataFromURL = result
        return result
    }
    
    
    
    }



enum APIError: Error {
    case invalidURL
    case invalidServerResponse
    case invalidData
}

extension APIError: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        switch self  {
            case.invalidURL:
                return "Bad URL"
            case .invalidServerResponse:
                return "The server did not return 200"
            case .invalidData:
                return "Their server returned bad data"
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't gotten further than grabbing the response from the URL. That is why once I start manipulating the data I'd like to use the response to find other things like what would a profit/loss with another item become. Which isn't the goal of this question at the moment.

Comment: If you make your keys integers (e.g. `let data: [Int: Datum]` and `let array = Item(data: [1: Datum(value: 1), 2: Datum(value: 2), 3: Datum(value: 3)])` and `let keyArray = [1, 2, 3]`), then you can use the `+ 1` sort of syntax.

Comment: @Rob yeah, it would work if the keys were truly numbers. But they are strings. Usually from JSON files, the keys are generally strings from what I've seen. I may be wrong. For the purpose of this question. The keys are for sure strings.

Comment: What is the purpose of Datum here? If you want the value to be an Int, then why isn't this `[String:Int]`?  If you mean `array.data[keyArray[0]]!.value`, then you can write that. If you mean you want to create a `+` operator that can add Datums and Ints, that's buildable. If you mean you want `1` to be interpreted as a Datum, and then have a `+` operator that can add Datums, that's also possible. But the way you've written it, you're trying to add `Datum + Int` and you haven't written any code to make that possible.

Comment: If you just want your code to compile all you need is `print(array.data[keyArray[0]]!.value + 1)` but I agree with @Rob here that this code doesn't make a lot of sense right now.

Comment: I see, I understand that it is abstract. I will fix it for it to be understood better. It'll take some time to give context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object model to parse that JSON would be:

```swift
struct Price: Decodable {
    let high: Int?
    let highTime: Date?
    let low: Int?
    let lowTime: Date?
}

struct ResponseObject: Decodable {
    let prices: [String: Price]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case prices = "data"
    }
}
```

(Note, the documentation says that either high or low might be missing, so we have to make them all optionals.)

Now, the id number is being passed as a string in the JSON/`ResponseObject`. But that is a number (look at [mapping](https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/mapping)). So, I would remap that dictionary so that the key was an integer, e.g.

```swift
enum ApiError: Error {
    case unknownError(Data?, URLResponse?)
}

func fetchLatestPrices(completion: @escaping (Result<[Int: Price], Error>) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            error == nil,
            let responseData = data,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
        else {
            completion(.failure(error ?? ApiError.unknownError(data, response)))
            return
        }

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        do {
            let responseObject = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: responseData)
            let keysAndValues = responseObject.prices.map { (Int($0.key)!, $0.value) }
            let prices = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: keysAndValues)
            completion(.success(prices))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

The code that converts that `[String: Price]` to a `[Int: Price]` is this:

```swift
let keysAndValues = responseObject.prices.map { (Int($0.key)!, $0.value) }
let prices = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: keysAndValues)
```

I must say that this is a questionable API design, to have keys returned as integers in one endpoint and as strings as another. But it is what it is. So, the above is how you handle that.

---

Anyway, now that you have a dictionary of prices, keyed by the id numbers, you can use that in your code, e.g.

```swift
var prices: [Int: Price] = [:]
var products: [Product] = []

let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
fetchLatestPrices { result in
    defer { group.leave() }

    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

    case .success(let values):
        prices = values
    }
}

group.enter()
fetchProducts { result in
    defer { group.leave() }

    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

    case .success(let values):
        products = values            }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) {
    for product in products {
        print(product.name, prices[product.id] ?? "no price found")
    }
}
```

Where

```swift
func fetchProducts(completion: @escaping (Result<[Product], Error>) -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/mapping")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            error == nil,
            let responseData = data,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200..<300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
        else {
            completion(.failure(error ?? ApiError.unknownError(data, response)))
            return
        }

        do {
            let products = try JSONDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: responseData)

            completion(.success(products))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And

```swift
struct Product: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let examine: String
    let members: Bool
    let lowalch: Int?
    let limit: Int?
    let value: Int
    let highalch: Int?
    let icon: String
}
```

(As an aside, I do not know if some of these other properties should be optionals or not. I just used optionals where I empirically discovered that they are occasionally missing.)